# Magento 2 custom module set the css and js file using the check the particular product attribute is enable or not

Tags: magento2, javascript, product-attribute, css

I have a custom module.I want to the add the css and js file if my custom product attribute value is available.

In xml I can't check product attribute value is available or not.

so what i do?

Please provide me the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding a layout handles (say **your_layout.xml**) using event observer ( for event layout_load_before) and then on the **your_layout.xml** you can add JS and CSS file.

Steps are given below.

I assume you are using a module names **"Company_MyModule**".

**step 1)**

create file **events.xml** under ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/etc/frontend***

File: ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/etc/frontend/events.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="layout_load_before">
        <observer name="productcustom_layout_handles" instance="Company\MyModule\Observer\AddHandles"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

**step 2)** 
Create the Observer class file **AddHandles.php** under ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/Observer***

File: 
***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/Observer/AddHandles.php***

```
<?php

    namespace Company\MyModule\Observer

    class AddHandles implements \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface
    {
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
         */
        protected $_registry;

        public function __construct(
           \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        )
        {
            $this->_registry = $registry;
        }


        public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
        {
            $product = $this->_registry->registry('current_product');

            if (!$product){
              return $this;
            }

            if($product->getMyCustomAttribute()){ // add your attribute condition
               $layout = $observer->getLayout();
               $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('your_layout'); 
            }

            return $this;
        }
    }
```

**step  3)**
 Create the layout fiile **your_layout.xml** under ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/***

File : ***YOUR-MAGENTO-ROOT/app/code/Company/MyModule/view/frontend/layout/your_layout.xml***

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
     <head>
         <css src="css/PATH-TO-CSS-FILE"/>
         <script src="js/PATH-TO-JS-FILE"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

**step 4)** Flush your magento cache

**NOTE**

Magento does not recommend to include js files using the head tag. So If your js file has written is  AMD format then you can include the JS file using require js .

For this, you need to add an extra block in your **your_layout.xml** file and under the block's PHTML file you need to load the JS files using require js.

Comment: You're welcome.